# How to filter data in DataGridView? C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview, combobox

I have a `ComboBox` and a `DataGridView`. I want to use a `ComboBox` to filter results in `DataGridView`. I'm thinking a `SelectionChanged` event handler is needed, but I am confused how to filter data once a user selects an option from the `ComboBox`.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: Please share your code..

Comment: do mvvm and use ICollectionView for filtering